# Use composite action output as step output

Tags: github-actions

If I have a composite action that provides and output I can then use that action in a step of a workflow that itself produces output as such:

```yaml
  Import-variables:
    …
    needs: [Import-message]
    outputs:
      foo: ${{ steps.foo.outputs.text }}
    steps:
      - name: Get foo variable
        id: get-foo
        uses: ./.github/actions/variable-from-pragma
        with:
          message: ${{ needs.Import-message.outputs.dequoted_message }}
          pragma: FOO
      - name: Set foo variable
        id: foo
        run: echo "text=${{ steps.get-foo.outputs.value }}" >> $GITHUB_OUTPUT
```

I can then later on use that second steps output by referring to `${{ needs.Import-variables.outputs.foo }}`

It just seems very cumbersome to have to use 2 steps, (`uses:`, `run:`) to get the output of the composite action into the job outputs.

Is there any way to get the output from the composite action into the step output of the step that calls the composite action, eliminating the need for the `run:` step?

Answer (score 0):

I don't know how your composite actions looks so for this

```
name: 'Hello World'
description: 'Greet someone'
inputs:
  who-to-greet:  # id of input
    description: 'Who to greet'
    required: true
    default: 'World'
outputs:
  random-number:
    description: "Random number"
    value: ${{ steps.random-number-generator.outputs.random-number }}
  random-number-bash:
    description: "Random number bash"
    value: ${{ steps.random-number-generator-bash.outputs.random-number-bash }}
runs:
  using: "composite"
  steps:
    - run: echo Hello ${{ inputs.who-to-greet }}.
      shell: bash
    - id: random-number-generator
      run: echo "random-number=$(echo $RANDOM)" >> $GITHUB_OUTPUT
      shell: bash
    - run: echo "${{ github.action_path }}" >> $GITHUB_PATH
      shell: bash
```

and this workflow

```
jobs:
  hello_world_job:
    runs-on: ubuntu-latest
    name: A job to say hello
    outputs:
        foo: ${{ steps.foo.outputs.random-number }}
    steps:
      - uses: actions/checkout@v3
      - id: foo
        uses: ./.github/actions/hello-world-composite-action-output
        with:
          who-to-greet: 'Mona the Octocat'
      - run: echo random-number ${{ steps.foo.outputs.random-number }}
        shell: bash
  job2:
    runs-on: ubuntu-latest
    needs: hello_world_job
    steps:
      - env:
           OUTPUT1: ${{needs.hello_world_job.outputs.foo}}
        run: echo "$OUTPUT1"
```

I got

[image]

and this is available in subsequent job:

[image]

Comment: Doesn't seem to work here. Isn't `- run: echo random-number ${{ steps.foo.outputs.random-number }}` a separate step from the `id: foo` step that is before it and thus requires it's own `id` to reference in the job's `outputs`?

Comment: Here's [my results](https://github.com/daos-stack/daos/actions/runs/6327940529/job/17184967341).  You can obviously see the [workflow file](https://github.com/daos-stack/daos/actions/runs/6327940529/workflow) from there.

Comment: I do not reference this as output of the job. I reference from composite action. Further step just show that value is available. Take a look full example here https://github.com/kmadof/github-actions-manual/blob/main/.github/workflows/so-051-output-composite.yaml

Comment: Oh yes, wow.  I see what you are doing there.  I am completely surprised that an action user can reach into the action's outputs.  This looks much better than my two-step implementation.  Thanx!